# Creating array of strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an array of flags for various types as:

```
Data Type1 Type2 Type3
12   1     0     0
14   0     1     0
3    0     1     0
45   0     0     1
```

I want to create the following array:

```
Data TypeName
12   Type1   
14   Type2   
3    Type2   
45   Type3
```

I tried creating an empty array of type strings as:

```
import numpy as np
z1 = np.empty(4, np.string_)
z1[np.where(Type1=1)] = 'Type1'
```

But this doesn't seem to give me desired results.

Edit:
I can use pandas dataframe and each row has only 1 type either Type1, Type2, Type3

Edit2:
Data Type1 Type2 Type3 are column names as in pandas dataframe but I was using numpy array with the implicit names as I have pointed in the example above.

Comment: Is the input a pandas dataframe? Would it always have exactly one `1` at each row starting from the second col?

Comment: Can you show us how could we create such an input array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach *abusing* the fact that we have exactly one `1` per row starting from `Type1` column with `idxmax()` to get the only occurrence of it per row -

```
pd.concat((df.Data, df.iloc[:,1:].idxmax(1)),axis=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
   Data  Type1  Type2  Type3
0    12      1      0      0
1    14      0      1      0
2     3      0      1      0
3    45      0      0      1

In [43]: pd.concat((df.Data, df.iloc[:,1:].idxmax(1)),axis=1)
Out[43]: 
   Data      0
0    12  Type1
1    14  Type2
2     3  Type2
3    45  Type3
```

Comment: I really like this solution. Actually you don't need `pd.concat` - `df.set_index('Data').idxmax(1).reset_index(name='TypeName')`

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** here is a mixture of [a brilliant @Divakar's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42703913/5741205) to use [DataFrame.idxmax(1)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) method and using `set_index()` and `reset_index()` in order to get rid of `pd.concat()`:

```
In [142]: df.set_index('Data').idxmax(1).reset_index(name='TypeName')
Out[142]:
   Data TypeName
0    12    Type1
1    14    Type2
2     3    Type2
3    45    Type3
```

**OLD answer:**

You can do it this way (Pandas solution):

```
In [132]: df.set_index('Data') \
            .stack() \
            .reset_index(name='val') \
            .query("val == 1") \
            .drop('val', 1)
Out[132]:
    Data level_1
0     12   Type1
4     14   Type2
7      3   Type2
11    45   Type3
```

Comment: You should add that suggestion of yours into your post. I think it's worth a mention in your post!

Comment: @Divakar, but the main idea here is to use `.idxmax(1)` - and you were first... ;)

Comment: Link to my post! But do add! :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be through

```
df.apply(lambda row: 'Type1' if row.Type1 else 'Type2' if row.Type2 else 'Type3', axis=1)
```

For example:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   Data  Type1  Type2  Type3
0    12      1      0      0
1    14      0      1      0
2     3      0      1      0
3    45      0      0      1

In [7]: df['TypeName'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'Type1' if row.Type1 else 'Type2' if row.Type2 else 'Type3', axis=1)

In [9]: df.drop(['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'], axis=1)
Out[9]: 
   Data TypeName
0    12    Type1
1    14    Type2
2     3    Type2
3    45    Type3
```